# html5 getusermedia() capture video without ssl

Tags: html, google-chrome, ssl, video, getusermedia

I need to capture video from webcam and upload it to my IIS.
I've used html5 and JS with webrtc to do this. All works fine, but chrome and opera sayed, that ssl is needed. How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid it; starting with Chrome 49, the `getUserMedia` API is only available in "secure contexts" (i.e. `https` sites and `localhost`).